# How to insert in to table $_POST['password']_hash("astkhlo", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

Tags: php, mysql

This is not working:-

```
$query= "INSERT INTO `members`(`name`,`email`,`password`)  VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email'])."','".$_POST['password']_hash("astkhlo",PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."')";
```

I am using xampp. It says

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_hash' (T_STRING)

Comment: In `$_POST['password']_hash`, the `_hash` is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Don't you mean: `password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`?  What is `astkhlo` ment to be? A salt?

Comment: learn about prepared statements

Comment: instead of using directly all the POST values, convert them to variable and use in query.Easier and correct approach

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes that's a salt. How to add a salt in password_hash?

Comment: @Davam . You don't need to, if you're using `password_hash()`, it takes care of that for you. Every password will have their own salts, making it more or less improbable to create a rainbow table for it. If you want to make it much more brute force safe, add a cost as a third parameter instead: `password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10])`. The higher the cost, the slower hashing = less efficient to brute force. And if you still want to use a salt, I recommend reading about how to generate a proper random and secure salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do something like below (a better approach):-

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query= "INSERT INTO members(name,email,password)  VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$password."')";
```

Note:-

Your script is still vulnerable to `SQL Injection`.

Try to Learn `prepared statements` to prevent from `SQL Injection`. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. @Anant can you tell me how to add a salt in it?

Comment: @Davam  check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870972/4248328  OR  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: @Davam - I would also recommend you to read this article: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm. It is lenghty, but if you actually respect your users, you really should read it all to understand what is and isn't secure and why. (Since a lot of people are reusing credentials, you are handling your users confidential information, after all).

Comment: @Anant 
How to query during login in case of password_hash?


 $query= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT=1 ";
    $result= mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

Is it ok?

Comment: yes that's seems correct.

Comment: @Anant Its not working. I cannot login.

Comment: check the error log files or do once `$result= mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: @Anant this is the error.

mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `password_hash()` under wrong syntax.

`password_hash` — Creates a password hash

`password_hash()` creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt(). Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with password_hash().

Replace your Insert Query with this one:

**Method One:**

```
$query= "INSERT INTO `members`(`name`,`email`,`password`)  VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email'])."','".password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."')";
```

**Method Two:**

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
$password =   password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$query= "INSERT INTO `members`(`name`,`email`,`password`)  VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$password."')";
```

Both the methods will produce the same output as expected but we are escaping the strings before itself in the method two.

**Example:**

```
<?php
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

> **Note:** Your Script is vulnerable to `SQL Injections` even thought use `escape the strings` before insertion. Try to use `prepared statements` so that it `avoids the SQL Injection`s that are possible in the Normal Query.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson. Thanks for spotting it Out and changed my answer as per the comment you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to write code reader friendly, and  use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for password.

**password_hash()** creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt(). Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with password_hash().

```
$name_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
$email_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
$password_value =password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query= "INSERT INTO members(name,email,password)  
VALUES('".$name_value."','".$email_value."','".$password_value."')";
```

Comment: Can someone explain the reason of vote down ?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you have a typo in your query. Missing space between INTO and the table name.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for letting me know the mistake.

Comment: @Mr.Developer  now you correct +1